# Two Sets That Are Transitive To Each Other

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Suppose R and S are reflexive relations on set A and T is a transitive relation on set A.
Prove or disprove each of these statements:

a) R ∪ T must be transitive.

I am trying to solve this, but what does it mean for T to be transitive to A?

Comment: $R$ must contain all $(a,a)$ (which $T$ may or not have) but $R$ may (or may not have) have other pairs.  There are no other rules or conditions on what pairs $R$ may have.  $R$ *could* have $(a,b)$.  Suppose $R$ has $(a,b)$ while $T$ has $(b,c)$ and neither of them have $(a,c)$.  Is that possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is a set.  $A\times A$, the cartesian cross product of $A$, is the set of all ordered pairs $(m,n); m,n \in A$.

$R,S, T$ are subsets of $A\times A$.

$R$ and $S$ are "reflexive to $A$" which means for every $a\in A$ then $(a,a)\in R$ and $(a,a) \in S$.

$T$ is transitive to $A$ means that for if $(a,b), (b,c) \in T$ then $(a,c)$ will also be in $T$.

Answer (score 0):

Relation $T$ being transitive means that if you have $xTy$ and $yTz$ you also have $xTz$.  Being on set $A$ just means that $x,y,z$ have to be from $A$.

Comment: Thank you! So I am wondering if R U T has be transitive because R is reflexive on A and T is from A meaning that that they would share all their elements? I don't know if I am understanding this.

Comment: You have two relations, which are sets of ordered pairs.  $R$ has to include all the pairs of the form $(x,x)$.  $T$ has to be transitive, so meet the condition above.  We then define a new relation that includes all the pairs from both.   The question is whether this relation has to be transitive.  You asked what the question means, and I think I explained that.  You need to think about whether something can make $R \cup T$ not be transitive.

Comment: "they would share all their elements"  Their elements are ordered pairs.  $R$ will have some ordered pairs.  $T$ ill have some ordered pairs.  There is no (immediate) reason to assume any correlation between the pairs that $R$ has and the pairs that $T$ has.